# how to fetch information from gmail based on given search keyword

Tags: rest, gmail-api

I was looking at google gmail API, i need to fetch information from gmail based on some keyword like "interview", "bills", "tickets" etc.
Can i do that using any gmail service ?

```
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get
```

i found one service which is

Users.messages: get

Requires authorization

Gets the specified message. Try it now or see an example.

Request

HTTP request

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/id
```

but  i don't understand what is id here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`id`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) is the ID of the message to retrieve. You may also refer with this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering) about *Searching for Messages*.

> You can search or filter files using the [`messages.list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) and [`threads.list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list) methods. These methods accept the `q` parameter which supports the same [advanced search syntax](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) as the Gmail web-interface. This means you can use search queries to filter messages by properties such as the sender, date, or label to name a few possibilities.